# Place a background image just below the navbar bootstrap-4 Beta

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to place a background image just below the navbar with **full height**. If I remove Bootstrap class `fixed-top`then background image automatically start below the navbar. In this situation what should I do?   How can I achieve this task?

```css
header#MyHeaderControl{ 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055297/pexels-photo-1055297.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Background image-->
<header class="" id="MyHeaderControl">
 
</header>
```

Comment: So, you want same view without `fixed-top` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `background-position: center 56px;` where `56px` is the height of `navbar`:

```css
header#MyHeaderControl{ 
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1055297/pexels-photo-1055297.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 56px;
  background-size: cover; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Background image-->
<header class="" id="MyHeaderControl">
 
</header>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same situation with the bootstrap carousel.    How Can I Fix It?   Please check: https://www.codeply.com/go/11JujOx93X

Comment: @Hasan [The docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#placement) recommend `padding-top` on the `<body>` to prevent overlap with other elements.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much, bro.

Answer (score 2):

You van use `calc` CSS property to achieve this. Just reduce the navbar height from header like this `height: calc(100vh - 56px);` and remove `fixed-top` class.

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwqjt97f/2/)

For more about `calc` css property please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you brother, Your information is very helpful.